# How to color different regions that are on one single layer

Tags: qgis, shapefile, dbf

I received the following files:

`.shp` `.shx` `.dbf`

I opened the shapefile using `QGIS 2.18` and I see there only one layer. I did `Add vector layer`.

I'd like to be able to color different regions with different colors.
Is this possible, having one single layer? How? (Even if by using another software)

I'm new to this. I did `Add vector layer` for importing. Maybe I could do this by importing the file differently, and not have one single layer.

Or maybe I could modify the `.dbf` file and add a new column for colors. I don't know.

My `.dbf` file looks like this:

[image]

Comment: This is a very basic task. Have you done any research, for example on QGIS help pages?

Comment: I actually did and could not reach the full solution (also exporting it back as shapefile containing colors)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click the layer in the "*Layers Panel*" (probably to the left of your QGIS window).

Select "*Properties*".

Select the "*Style*" tab on the left hand side of the window that pops up.

Select the first dropdown menu at the top and choose "*Categorized*".

Select the column you would like to colour by in the second dropdown menu.

Left click classify below the large white box. This will populate the white box with a list of the varients in the selected attribute. You can keep the defualt colours or double click on the colour to the left of each category and choose your own.

Should look something like this:

[image]

`.shx` is the index for the shapefile, `.dbf` is your attribute table for the shapefile. Keep all three files together.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. I choose `Random colors`, but when I choose from `Column` dropdown, nothing appears...

Comment: Sorry, my bad, forgot to clcik classify. It seems to work. The only problem I have now is: Could I export the new colored map again as the export I did? (those 3 files only)?

Comment: I'd like to know if somehow I can add a new colum in the `dbf` representing colors...

Comment: What exaclty are you trying to accomplish? Your colours should represent something else, i.e. a differentiating attribute. What do you want to export? The colur scheme? A static map? Another shapefile? If you really want to add another column, toggle the layer into editing mode (the pencil button) open the attribute table, and select the *Add new field* button.

Comment: Let me try to explain one more time. I want to somehow have a color attribute inside my shapefile. How do I do it? Could I just add a column in the dbf? Or maybe edit the shapefile / shx? I tried `right click layer -> save layer as` but the colors are not saved.

Comment: Or is it better to post a new stack question about this?

Comment: No, again, what exaclty are you trying to accomplish? If you want to save the colour scheme, you must save a *Style File* `.qml` then load that `.qml` to any other instace you open the shapefile. The colour cannot be directly saved to the shapefile.

Comment: What about adding a new `color` column in the dbf? You think it could help with something?
Also, thanks a lot for all the answers, greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Ben - **Do not modify the .dbf file manually**. You could quite easily corrupt your data and shapefile. You can use the _Field Calculator_ on your layer to add a new column which can contain a string representation of colours :)